# Why postNotification fail in the second call in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, nsnotificationcenter

Firs I call a method from locationManager for update the location(didUpdateLocations).
Into this method I use a postNotification and all is ok. 
But when I call in a second time the method from locationManager, appears a mistake, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[**NSMallocBlock** sendMessageNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17026fac0'"

[Mistake in on info variable]

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    debugLog("locations \(locations)")

    if let location = locations.last {

        let mMessage = Message()
        mMessage.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        mMessage.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        let userInfo = ["message": JSONSerializer.toJson(mMessage)]

        if !userInfo.isEmpty {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("__SEND_MESSAGE__",
                object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please show your code and the stack trace, but it looks you are somehow referencing released memory.

Comment: I added the method but in the stack trace only say Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMallocBlock sendMessageNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17026fac0'

Comment: Why do you serialise the object into JSON? You could just add the Message object to the dictionary. In fact you could just add the location or location.coordinate object

Comment: The thing is I send in Json data to the server.

Comment: Then you should convert to JSON before you send it to the server.  It doesn't make sense to do it here.  Regardless there should be no reason why this code should cause a crash.  You need to look at the stack track to see where it was in your code that it tried to call that function `sendMessageNotification`

Comment: Post your code where you `addObserver` of the notification.

Comment: @Paulw11  `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "sendMessage:",
            name: "__SEND_MESSAGE__",
            object: nil)`

Comment: Are you unregistering the observer when the object is deallocated?  Your crash looks like a method was called on a deallocated object. Do you set `sendMessageNotification` as the notification handler anywhere?

Comment: I didn't use unregister yet, and I have other observer with the same selector.

Comment: In the second call appear this: -[__NSCFSet sendMessageNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17407bac0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1834b82d8 0x19512c0e4 0x1834bf3a4 0x1834bc154 0x1833beccc 0x18345e2c4 0x18339b450 0x1842caa80 0x100153900 0x1000e1b18 0x101b58fd4 0x101b58f94 0x101b5dc28 0x18346f7f8 0x18346d8a0 0x1833992d4 0x18cdf76fc 0x187f96f40 0x10020ee38 0x1957d6a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

In my code was missing a remove observer, in the same class where I added the notification.

```
deinit {
    // perform the deinitialization
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Thanks.